Java Maven: exec-maven-plugin executes several times
[MOTIVATION]
I have a GWT parent project that has 3 sub projects, as below:

D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\pom.xml
D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\pom.xml
D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\pom.xml
D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\pom.xml

I want the war file to be upgraded to jakarta automatically, with exec-maven-plugin.
[PROBLEMS]

However, exec-maven-plugin triggers several times (once for every project).
Furtermore, if I delete the target folders, maven gives below error, as I configured exec-maven-plugin for war file only.

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot read source location [D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\war\app-backup.war]

[QUESTION]
Is it possile to run it only for assembly (only after war file combined)?
[PARENT POM FILE (that contains exec-maven-plugin)]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.tugalsan.app.backup</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.gwtproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <finalName>app-backup</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>false</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <launcherDir>${basedir}/app-welcome-server/target/classes/launcherDir/</launcherDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clean_and_upgrade</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <commandlineArgs>-jar D:/git/api/com.tugalsan.api.migration.jakarta/target/jakartaee-migration-1.0.9-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar D:/git/app/com.tugalsan.app.backup/com.tugalsan.app.backup-server/target/war/app-backup.war D:/bin/tomcat/home/webapps/app-backup.war</commandlineArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>22</release>
                        <enablePreview>true</enablePreview>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>--add-modules</arg>
                            <arg>jdk.incubator.vector</arg>
                            <!-- <arg>-XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading -->
                        </compilerArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceLevel>11</sourceLevel><!-- gwt cannot compile up -->
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/war</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>com.tugalsan.app.backup-client</module>
        <module>com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared</module>
        <module>com.tugalsan.app.backup-server</module>
    </modules>
</project>

[OUTPUT]
cd D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup; JAVA_HOME=D:\\bin\\java\\home M2_HOME=D:\\bin\\maven\\home cmd /c "\"D:\\bin\\maven\\home\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=D:\\bin\\netbeans\\home\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar --no-transfer-progress clean install"
Scanning for projects...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Build Order:

com.tugalsan.app.backup                                            [pom]
com.tugalsan.app.backup.client                                 [gwt-app]
com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared                                     [jar]
com.tugalsan.app.backup.server                                     [war]

----------------< com.tugalsan:com.tugalsan.app.backup >----------------
Building com.tugalsan.app.backup 1.0-SNAPSHOT                      [1/4]
  from pom.xml
--------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------

--- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup ---

--- exec:3.2.0:exec (clean_and_upgrade) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup ---
!!!   Logger Level = INFO
Performing migration from source [D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\war\app-backup.war] to destination [D:\bin\tomcat\home\webapps\app-backup.war] with Jakarta EE specification profile [TOMCAT]
Migration starting for archive [app-backup.war] using streaming
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/apache-el-8.5.70.jar] using streaming
...
...
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar] using streaming
Migration finished for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar]
Migration finished for archive [app-backup.war]
Migration completed successfully in [10,889] milliseconds

--- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup ---
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\pom.xml to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

------------< com.tugalsan:com.tugalsan.app.backup.client >-------------
Building com.tugalsan.app.backup.client 1.0-SNAPSHOT               [2/4]
  from com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\pom.xml
------------------------------[ gwt-app ]-------------------------------

--- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
Deleting D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\target

--- gwt:1.1.0:enforce-encoding (default-enforce-encoding) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---

--- gwt:1.1.0:add-super-sources (default-add-super-sources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---

--- gwt:1.1.0:add-test-super-sources (default-add-test-super-sources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---

--- gwt:1.1.0:generate-module (default-generate-module) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---

--- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\src\main\resources
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\src\main\super

--- compiler:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
Recompiling the module because of changed source code.
Compiling 3 source files with javac [debug preview release 22] to target\classes

--- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\src\test\resources
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\src\test\super

--- compiler:3.12.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
Recompiling the module because of changed dependency.

--- gwt:1.1.0:test (default-test) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---

--- gwt:1.1.0:compile (default-compile) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
Compiling module com.tugalsan.app.backup.App
   Compiling 2 permutations
      Compiling permutation 0...
      Compiling permutation 1...
   Compile of permutations succeeded
   Compilation succeeded -- 17,272s
Linking into D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\target\app-backup\app
   Link succeeded
   Linking succeeded -- 0,225s

--- gwt:1.1.0:package-app (default-package-app) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
Building war: D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\target\app-backup.war

--- exec:3.2.0:exec (clean_and_upgrade) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
!!!   Logger Level = INFO
Performing migration from source [D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\war\app-backup.war] to destination [D:\bin\tomcat\home\webapps\app-backup.war] with Jakarta EE specification profile [TOMCAT]
Migration starting for archive [app-backup.war] using streaming
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/apache-el-8.5.70.jar] using streaming
...
...
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar] using streaming
Migration finished for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar]
Migration finished for archive [app-backup.war]
Migration completed successfully in [10,792] milliseconds

--- install:3.1.2:install (default-install) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ---
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\pom.xml to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup.client\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup.client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-client\target\app-backup.war to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup.client\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup.client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

------------< com.tugalsan:com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared >-------------
Building com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared 1.0-SNAPSHOT               [3/4]
  from com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\pom.xml
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
Deleting D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\target

--- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\src\main\resources

--- compiler:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
Can't extract module name from xalan-2.7.2.jar: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in JAR file xalan-2.7.2.jar
Recompiling the module because of changed source code.
Compiling 2 source files with javac [debug preview release 22] to target\classes

--- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\src\test\resources

--- compiler:3.12.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
Can't extract module name from xalan-2.7.2.jar: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in JAR file xalan-2.7.2.jar
Recompiling the module because of changed dependency.

--- surefire:3.2.2:test (default-test) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---

--- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
Building jar: D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\target\app-backup.jar

--- exec:3.2.0:exec (clean_and_upgrade) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
!!!   Logger Level = INFO
Performing migration from source [D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\war\app-backup.war] to destination [D:\bin\tomcat\home\webapps\app-backup.war] with Jakarta EE specification profile [TOMCAT]
Migration starting for archive [app-backup.war] using streaming
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/apache-el-8.5.70.jar] using streaming
...
...
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar] using streaming
Migration finished for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar]
Migration finished for archive [app-backup.war]
Migration completed successfully in [10,853] milliseconds

--- source:3.3.0:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
Building jar: D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\target\app-backup-sources.jar

--- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ---
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\pom.xml to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\target\app-backup.jar to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-shared\target\app-backup-sources.jar to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar

------------< com.tugalsan:com.tugalsan.app.backup.server >-------------
Building com.tugalsan.app.backup.server 1.0-SNAPSHOT               [4/4]
  from com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\pom.xml
--------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------

--- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
Deleting D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target

--- resources:3.3.1:copy-resources (copy-resources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources\public to target\app-backup

--- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes

--- compiler:3.12.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
Can't extract module name from xalan-2.7.2.jar: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in JAR file xalan-2.7.2.jar
Required filename-based automodules detected: [gwt-user-2.11.0.jar, javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar, zip4j-2.11.5.jar, tomcat-jdbc-11.0.0-M13.jar, javamelody-core-1.95.0.jar, commons-math3-3.6.1.jar, jericho-html-3.4.jar, gwt-crypto-2.3.0.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository!
Recompiling the module because of changed dependency.
Compiling 2 source files with javac [debug preview release 22 module-path] to target\classes

--- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\src\test\resources

--- compiler:3.12.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
Can't extract module name from xalan-2.7.2.jar: Provider class org.apache.bsf.BSFManager not in JAR file xalan-2.7.2.jar
Recompiling the module because of changed dependency.

--- surefire:3.2.2:test (default-test) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---

--- war:3.4.0:war (default-war) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
Packaging webapp
Assembling webapp [com.tugalsan.app.backup.server] in [D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\app-backup]
Processing war project
Copying webapp resources [D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\src\main\webapp]
Processing overlay [ id com.tugalsan:com.tugalsan.app.backup.client]
Building war: D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\war\app-backup.war

--- exec:3.2.0:exec (clean_and_upgrade) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
!!!   Logger Level = INFO
Performing migration from source [D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\war\app-backup.war] to destination [D:\bin\tomcat\home\webapps\app-backup.war] with Jakarta EE specification profile [TOMCAT]
Migration starting for archive [app-backup.war] using streaming
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/apache-el-8.5.70.jar] using streaming
...
...
Migration starting for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar] using streaming
Migration finished for archive [WEB-INF/lib/zip4j-2.11.5.jar]
Migration finished for archive [app-backup.war]
Migration completed successfully in [10,844] milliseconds

--- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ---
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\pom.xml to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup.server\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup.server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Installing D:\git\app\com.tugalsan.app.backup\com.tugalsan.app.backup-server\target\war\app-backup.war to C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\com\tugalsan\com.tugalsan.app.backup.server\1.0-SNAPSHOT\com.tugalsan.app.backup.server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Summary for com.tugalsan.app.backup 1.0-SNAPSHOT:

com.tugalsan.app.backup ............................ SUCCESS [ 11.445 s]
com.tugalsan.app.backup.client ..................... SUCCESS [ 31.812 s]
com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared ..................... SUCCESS [ 12.237 s]
com.tugalsan.app.backup.server ..................... SUCCESS [ 13.877 s]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  01:09 min
Finished at: 2024-05-06T13:04:27+03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------



I found the answer, one minute after posting the question.
I think the war file is compiled in sub-project com.tugalsan.app.backup-server, not parent.
To try it, I have moved the exec-maven-plugin to com.tugalsan.app.backup-server pom, and it triggered correctly.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tugalsan</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.tugalsan.app.backup</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>com.tugalsan.app.backup.server</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.tugalsan.app.backup.shared</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed if you are using GWT-RPC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gwtproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.tugalsan.lib.boot</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.tugalsan.api.gwt.jdk</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app-backup</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/public/</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clean_and_upgrade</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <commandlineArgs>-jar D:/git/api/com.tugalsan.api.migration.jakarta/target/jakartaee-migration-1.0.9-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar D:/git/app/com.tugalsan.app.backup/com.tugalsan.app.backup-server/target/war/app-backup.war D:/bin/tomcat/home/webapps/app-backup.war</commandlineArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- XXX: We want to exclude app-backup-client from 'env-dev' profile, Maven forces us to make a 'env-prod' profile -->
            <id>env-prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>com.tugalsan.app.backup.client</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>env-dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>


You used SO to formulate your question - rubber ducking - which is why you could then find the solution.  Well done.
